# A question about existential generalization

Tags: logic

Let $\circ$ be an associative binary operation. Starting from $w=(x \circ y) \circ z$, can I deduce $\exists k \left(w=k \circ z\right)$ by existential generalization? $w=x \circ z \rightarrow \exists k \left(w=k \circ z\right)$ is of course correct, but here "$x$" is a single symbol. $(x \circ y)$ is a valid value for $k$, but on the other hand, "$(x \circ y)$" is a composite symbol.

Comment: Certainly it's _logically_ correct. In ordinary math, you could say: Let $u=x \circ y$, and then the claim $\exists k \left(w=k \circ z\right)$ would be immediate. I guess it depends on your formal system.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_generalization is pretty standard.  It applies even when you are converting a "composite symbol" to a single atomic variable, such as $1 + 1 = 2 \vdash \exists x ~:~ x = 2$

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I have no particular logical system in mind. If you can suggest one in which this kind of reasoning is valid, that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Existential Introduction *from* $(x\circ y)$ is quite valid.   If $w$ does equal $(x\circ y)\circ z$, then that is a witness that there is *something* which, when $\circ$-ed by $z$, does equal $w$.$$\exists \kappa~( w=\kappa\circ z)$$

Indeed, that something is $(x\circ y)$.   It is a composite of two free variables and a binary operator, but still an entity in itself.  $$w=(x\circ y)\circ z ~{~\vdash~ \exists \kappa~(\kappa=(x\circ y)~\wedge~w=\kappa\circ z)\\~\vdash~ \exists \kappa~(w=\kappa\circ z)}$$

---

However.

Existential Elimination *to* $(x\circ y)$ *may* not be plausible, depending on the nature of the operator and its valid arguments.   That something may be $\circ$-ed by $z$ to equal $w$ does not *necessarily* mean that something is of the form $(x\circ y)$, unless the properties of $\circ$ and the domain of discussion allow it to be plausible.

Does $\forall k\exists x\exists y~(k=x\circ y)$?   If not, all you can say is:

$$\exists \kappa~(w=\kappa\circ z)~\vdash~ w=k\circ z$$

Comment: It seems as though you have written "universal" in a couple of places where you intend "existential".

Answer (score 0):

This is what I want to prove:

$\exists\delta\left((\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\delta\right)\rightarrow\exists\varepsilon\left(\alpha\circ\beta=\varepsilon\right)$

It is a very usefull proposition, because it allows us to logically extract a duplex of objects from a triad. I thought of this proof. The only doubtful point is in line 4, which corresponds to my question.

Proof

1. $\exists\delta\left((\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\delta\right)$
   (assumption)
2. $\exists\delta\left((\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\delta\right)\rightarrow(\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\eta$
   (EI on 1)
3. $(\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\eta$ 
   (M.P. 1,2)
4. $(\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\eta\rightarrow\exists\kappa\left(\kappa\circ\gamma=\eta\right)$
   (EG on 3)
5. $\exists\kappa\left(\kappa\circ\gamma=\eta\right)$
   (M.P. 3,4)
6. $\exists\kappa\left(\kappa\circ\gamma=\eta\right)\rightarrow\lambda\circ\gamma=\eta$
   (EI on 5)
7. $\lambda\circ\gamma=\eta$
   (M.P. 5,6)
8. $\lambda\circ\gamma=\eta\rightarrow\gamma\circ\lambda=\eta$
   (axiom 1)
9. $\gamma\circ\lambda=\eta$
   (M.P. 7,8)
10. $(\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\eta\rightarrow\gamma\circ(\alpha\circ\beta)=\eta$
    (axiom 1)
11. $\gamma\circ(\alpha\circ\beta)=\eta$
    (M.P. 9,10)
12. $\gamma\circ(\alpha\circ\beta)=\eta\rightarrow\left(\gamma\circ\lambda=\eta\rightarrow\gamma\circ\lambda=\gamma\circ(\alpha\circ\beta)\right)$
    (replacement rule: $x=y\rightarrow\left(F(x)\rightarrow F(y)\right)$
13. $\gamma\circ\lambda=\eta\rightarrow\gamma\circ\lambda=\gamma\circ(\alpha\circ\beta)$
    (M.P. 11,12)
14. $\gamma\circ\lambda=\gamma\circ(\alpha\circ\beta)$
    (M.P. 9,13)
15. $\gamma\circ\lambda=\gamma\circ(\alpha\circ\beta)\rightarrow\lambda=(\alpha\circ\beta)$
    (axiom 2)
16. $\lambda=(\alpha\circ\beta)$
    (M.P. 14,15)
17. $\lambda=(\alpha\circ\beta)\rightarrow\exists\varepsilon\left(\varepsilon=\alpha\circ\beta\right)$
    (EG on 16)
18. $\exists\varepsilon\left(\varepsilon=\alpha\circ\beta\right)$
    (M.P. 16,17)

$\exists\delta\left((\alpha\circ\beta)\circ\gamma=\delta\right)\vdash\exists\varepsilon\left(\alpha\circ\beta=\varepsilon\right)$

Comment: In ordinary first-order logic, this proof is unnecessary; you could simply have $a \circ b = a \circ b$ (which is an axiom of equality) and use existential generalization to go to $\exists \epsilon (a \circ b = \epsilon)$. The antecedent doesn't even factor into it.

Comment: It does not work like that. $(\alpha\circ\beta)$ may have no meaning, so the sentence $a \circ b = a \circ b$ will be false. There is a limitation on whether objects $\alpha$ and $\beta$ can be the arguments of $\circ$. As for example, in arithmetic, when working only with natural numbers, "$\alpha-b$" makes no sense for any $\alpha ,\beta$. It makes sense only when $\alpha > \beta$. With your suggestion, you can prove that $\exists \epsilon (\alpha - \beta = \epsilon)$ even when $\alpha < \beta$.

Comment: This is not standard first order logic. If you are working in a first order logic with partial functions you should specify how that logic works.

Comment: What does "standard first order logic" means? (I'm not a mathematician). What is the difference with first order logic in general?

Comment: First order logics are logics which look like what you have written: first-order variables, function symbols, which form terms, relation symbols (including $=$), which form atomic formulas, and then propositional connectives $\land, \lor, \to, \neg$ and quantification over first-order variables $\exists x, \forall y$ to form formulas. There is a more or less standard form of first order logic, which is what I (and I assume most people on this site) will assume your logic is unless otherwise specified. This logic only has total functions. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic

Comment: I did not know that FOL has only total functions. This is very helpful, thank you.